# How do I download a file in chunks using NIO channels?

Tags: java, http, download, nio

The server which serves the file I am downloading limits users to a 10-megabyte per second download speed. If there is any speed greater, the user will be throttled. In order to achieve this, I attempted to write a loop and keep track of what specific range of bytes to download, and then create an HTTP request to download those bytes (using the `Range` header). I came up with the following method to get an `InputStream` of those bytes.

```java
  private InputStream createRequest(final String source, final long start, final long end)
      throws URISyntaxException, IOException, InterruptedException {

    final HttpRequest.Builder builder = HttpRequest.newBuilder();
    builder.uri(new URI(source));
    builder.header("User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 7.0; SM-G892A Build/NRD90M; wv) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/4.0 Chrome/67.0.3396.87 Mobile Safari/537.36'");
    builder.header("Range", "Bytes=%s-%s".formatted(start, end));

    final HttpResponse<InputStream> stream = HTTP_CLIENT.send(builder.build(), BodyHandlers.ofInputStream());
    if (stream.statusCode() == 200) {
      return stream.body();
    }

    throw new AssertionError("Failed to download data from URL!");
  }
```

However, in my main code:

```java
  private void downloadInChunks(@NotNull final String source, @NotNull final Path path)
      throws IOException, URISyntaxException, InterruptedException {

    final long size = 10 * 1_000_000;
    long start = 0;
    long end = size;

    ReadableByteChannel in = Channels.newChannel(this.createRequest(source, start, end));
    final FileChannel out = new FileOutputStream(path.toFile()).getChannel();

    while (??? what condition here) {
      out.transferFrom(in, start, size);
      start = end;
      end += size;
      in = Channels.newChannel(this.createRequest(source, start, end));
    }

  }
```

I have an issue where I am not sure when to stop. I could get the file size (in bytes) and divide it into 10-megabyte chunks; however, I would not be sure how to handle the "remainder" bytes in the last chunk that have not been downloaded (as not all files would be evenly divided with 10-megabyte chunks). What condition should I use and how should I handle downloading the remaining chunk?

Comment: It wouldn't fit directly into your current code, but you could call [`read()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/channels/ReadableByteChannel.html#read-java.nio.ByteBuffer-) on the channel, and it will return _"The number of bytes read, possibly zero, or -1 if the channel has reached end-of-stream"_.

Comment: "10-megabyte" isn't a speed.  "10 megabytes per second" might be.  It looks like you've conflated those more tightly than necessary -- reading in 10MB chunks isn't necessary to achieve the goal of reading a stream at 10 MB per second.